# How to check if a hydra is displaying?

Tags: hydra

If a hydra is opened, how do we check programmatically that it is actually open and displaying?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit, to make your question clearer to more people who might be able to help?

Comment: I want to check for a flag determining the status of a hydra. I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Please put any such clarifications into the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to check for a variable `hydra-curr-map`. This will return `nil` if the hydra is hidden or the keymap that it's using given by `<hydra>/keymap`.
ie.

```lisp
;; define hydra
(defhydra test-hydra ....)

;; open test-hydra
(test-hydra/body)

(eq hydra-curr-map test-hydra/keymap)
=> t
```

Comment: Just curiosity. What is the reason that you need to test it?

Comment: @itirazimvar I wanted to make a toggle (1. if A is off and A is pressed, close A, 2. if A is on and A is pressed, open A, 3. if A is on and B is pressed, close A and open B)